# Compare features in two images in OpenCV vc++

Tags: c++, opencv, pattern-matching

I have to compare two images in OpenCV, both are black and white and have white edges, I would like to get a sort of percentage result by comparing these two images. What should i do?

[image]

1st image and

[image]

2nd image

Can someone advice on how to perform this operation?

Comment: The question is very subjective. What is your definition of the percentage result of the comparison? How would you quantify that the images are 30% similar to each other, for example? Are you going to count the number of pixels that are exactly the same at the same position or maybe want to use some other measure for comparison?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input and output?

Comment: Having a clear view of what it is you want to compute exactly might help.

Comment: Its more of pattern matching, I want to see if the lines overlap. Image sizes may vary. If i have the first image as template, i want to see how much of the lines match/overlap lines on the other image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple black and white images, you can try [compare](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare):

```
cv::Mat img1 = ...
cv::Mat img2 = ...
cv::Mat result = ...

cv::compare(img1 , img2  , result , cv::CMP_EQ );
int percentage  = countNonZero(result);
```

However, for more advanced comparisons, there are different approaches such as extracting matching areas with [matchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

Comment: I tried cv::compare, but results were't satisfactory. MatchTemplate is better. especially for a large image. Thank you